# Make nested divs' width fill to the browser

Tags: html, css

Actually this is a problem I encountered during the developing of blogger.

I want to write a navbar on my own, but the width of parent elements limit the style `width:100%`, even if I set the float properties to it.[image]

Please see the image above. Only `nav`'s HTML/JS/CSS are configurable. So how can I configure the CSS Style of class `nav` to archive this goal?

Or, If you have relevent experience in developing blogger, please tell me.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use position absolute for your nav. [Look at this FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cRgEC/)

html :

```
<div class="first">0</div>
<div>
    1
    <div class="nav">NAV</div>
</div>
<div>2</div>
```

css :

```
div { background: grey; width: 75px; height: 50px; margin: 20px auto; }
.first { margin-top: 75px; }
.nav { background: red; position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 0px; width: 100%; margin: 0; }
```

**EDIT**

Your nav is in a `position:relative;` well you can append your nav to your body with that jquery ([HERE THE FIDDLE UPDATED](http://jsfiddle.net/cRgEC/2/)):

```
$(".nav").appendTo("body");
```

Comment: Thank you for your demo! . However I discovered that due to one parent element's `position: relative;` propertise, my `nav` cannot escape from it. I here simulate it in jsfiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/helisz/cRgEC/1/

Answer (score 1):

To achieve that kind of 'layering' you probably need to use absolute positioning, especially if your options are limited. This has the obvious caveat of taking it out of the page's flow, so you'll need to ensure your page is never too short for it to be visible. It won't affect other elements around it either.

So, something like:

```
nav {
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 400px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Hopefully one of its parents has a `position: relative;` so the `nav` knows where to use as an origin point when positioning absolutely, otherwise it'll use the top left of the browser pane.

You may also need a `z-index` value if you want your `nav` to appear behind the content.

Comment: Thanks for replying. However I discovered that due to one parent element's `position: relative;`propertise, my nav cannot escape from it. I here simulate it in jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/helisz/cRgEC/1/

Comment: @Darklizard That's a definite issue, especially assuming you can't control that parent `div`. Would using something like `width: 5000px;` work for your needs? If JavaScript were an option you could also use that to dynamically set the width of your `nav` to match the browser pane. A jQuery solution would be something like `$(window).resize(function () { $('nav').width($(window).width()); });`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are searching for, but you can try giving your naviation `position: absolute;` and `width: 100%;`. This will get the navigation element out of the flow of the document.